Amplify v6 uploadData: [AccessDenied: Access Denied] error when uploading file in React Native Expo
I'm migrating my React Native app using Expo and AWS Amplify from version 5 to version 6. I am encountering an AccessDenied: Access Denied error when trying to upload a file to S3 using the uploadData method.
Here is my code for version 5 which works fine:
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

export async function uploadImage(uri: string): Promise<string | null> {
  try {
    if (!uri) {
      throw new Error('Invalid URI provided for uploading the image');
    }
    const id = uuid.v4().toString();  // Generate a version 4 UUID
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    if (!response.ok && response.type !== 'default') {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const blob = await response.blob();
    if (!blob) {
      throw new Error('Failed to convert the response to a blob');
    }
    const result = await Storage.put(id, blob);
    if (!result.key) {
      throw new Error('Failed to upload the image');
    }
    return result.key;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading file: ', err);
    return null;
  }
}

And here is my code for version 6 which gives the AccessDenied error:
import { getUrl, uploadData } from 'aws-amplify/storage';

export async function uploadImage(uri: string): Promise<string | null> {
  try {
    if (!uri) {
      throw new Error('Invalid URI provided for uploading the image');
    }
    const id = uuid.v4().toString();  // Generate a version 4 UUID
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    if (!response.ok && response.type !== 'default') {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const blob = await response.blob();
    if (!blob) {
      throw new Error('Failed to convert the response to a blob');
    }
    console.log('id', id);
    console.log('blob', blob);
    const operation = uploadData({ path: id, data: blob })
    const result = await operation.result
    console.log('result', result);
    if (!result.path) {
      throw new Error('Failed to upload the image');
    }
    return result.path;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading file: ', err);
    return null;
  }
}

The error message is:
Error uploading file: [AccessDenied: Access Denied]

From my understanding, the issue might be related to the path used in uploadData. How should I correctly specify the path or set the access levels to fix this error?

When migrating from Amplify v5 to v6, there are some changes in how paths and access levels are managed for S3 uploads. In v6, you need to explicitly specify the access level in the path.
Here is the corrected code for v6:
import { uploadData } from 'aws-amplify/storage';
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

export async function uploadImage(uri: string): Promise<string | null> {
  try {
    if (!uri) {
      throw new Error('Invalid URI provided for uploading the image');
    }
    const id = uuid.v4().toString();  // Generate a version 4 UUID
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    if (!response.ok && response.type !== 'default') {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const blob = await response.blob();
    if (!blob) {
      throw new Error('Failed to convert the response to a blob');
    }
    console.log('id', id);
    console.log('blob', blob);
    const operation = uploadData({ path: `public/${id}`, data: blob })  // Specify the public access level in the path
    const result = await operation.result
    console.log('result', result);
    if (!result.path) {
      throw new Error('Failed to upload the image');
    }
    return result.path;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading file: ', err);
    return null;
  }
}

Explanation:
Access Levels in Path:
In v6, you need to specify the access level in the path for the uploadData method. By default, the access level is set to public, but you need to include this explicitly in your path like public/{id}.
Documentation Reference:
According to the Amplify documentation, the path must include the access level prefix:
Public: Accessible by all users of your app. Files are stored under the public/ path in your S3 bucket.
Protected: Readable by all users, but writable only by the creating user. Files are stored under protected/{user_identity_id}/.
Private: Only accessible for the individual user. Files are stored under private/{user_identity_id}/.
References:

File access levels
Amplify Docs > Gen 1 > v6 > uploadData

This change should resolve the AccessDenied error you're encountering. If you have further issues, ensure your IAM policies and S3 bucket policies are correctly configured to allow the necessary permissions.
